# How to pass file lines as argument in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I’m learning Nim and I have a simple program that reads lines of a file. I would like to make it testable by extracting the main code in a function that takes an iterable of lines:

```
func countLines(lines: iterator): int =
  var n = 0
  for _ in lines:
    n += 1
  return n

if isMainModule:
    echo(countLines(lines "some_file.txt"))
```

The code above [doesn’t compile](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=4iq4) because of the following error: `Error: attempting to call routine: 'lines'`.

If I remove the superfluous code, I still get the same error:

```
echo(lines "some_file.txt")
```

Why can’t I get the result of `lines "some_file.txt"` and pass it around? Is there some way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be useful:
https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#iterators-and-the-for-statement-firstminusclass-iterators

We could create an intermediate iterator marked as `closure` that uses the inline `lines`:

```
iterator lines(f: string): string {.closure.} =
  for line in io.lines(f):
    yield line

func countLines(l: iterator(f: string): string, f: string): int =
  var n = 0
  for _ in ls(f):
    n += 1
  return n

when isMainModule:
  echo countLines(lines, "some_file.txt")
```

Nim allows you to write `countLines` in this way:

```
func countLines(l: iterator(f: string): string, f: string): int =
  for _ in ls(f):
    inc result
```

As `result` is auto-created and auto-returned.